# String that cannot be represented in UTF-8

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I am creating a set of tests for the size of a `String` to do so I am using something like this `myString.getBytes("UTF-8").length > MAX_SIZE` for which java has a checked exception `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Just for curiosity, and to further consider other possible test scenarios, is there a text that cannot be represented by UTF-8 character encoding?

BTW: I did my homework, but nowhere (that I can find) specifies that indeed UTF-8/Unicode includes ALL the characters which are possible. I know that its size is 2^32 and many of them are still empty, but the question remains.

Comment: what if the String is already encoded using something else?

Comment: as far as my understanding goes UTF-8 should be capable of enclose *any other encoding* (please don't take this literal, it is nothing but an assumption)

Comment: UTF-8 is one way to encode the entire Unicode code set. UTF-16 is another. All of the known Unicode code points can be encoded in UTF-8 as well as in UTF-16. UTF-8 needs up to 4 bytes for that, UTF-16 up to two 16 bit values. But not all 4 byte combinations are valid UTF-8 or UTF-16 code points.

Comment: Of course you could design your own "character" and use it in your graphics. But that would not make it a Unicode code point yet. So while it is possible, it is not necessarily Unicode. Which symbols are in Unicode is a decision made by a committee, AFAIK.

Comment: UTF-8 by definition is capable of representing all Unicode code points.
There are some bit patterns that do not represent valid UTF-8 encodings, but that is like saying there are combinations of letters that don't represent valid English words.  UTF-8 encoding of a UTF-16 string can cause the result to be longer than the input but in all but pathological cases the UTF-8 will be _shorter_ than the UTF-16 since characters from the standard ASCII set occupy 1 octet in UTF-8 vs 2 octets in UTF-16.  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking that `UnsupportedEncodingException` will be thrown if the string can't be represented in UTF-8.  That's not what it's for.  The exception is if you specify an encoding that the JVM doesn't even know about, e.g. `myString.getBytes("nonsense")`.  But every Java implementation is required to support UTF-8 (see the table of [standard charsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)), and you can avoid having to write a `catch` block by using `myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The official FAQ from the Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) is pretty clear on the matter, and is a great source of information on all questions related to UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.

In particular, notice the following quote (emphasis mine):

> **Q: What is a UTF?**
>
> A: A Unicode transformation format (UTF) is an
> algorithmic mapping from ***every*** Unicode code point (***except surrogate
> code points***) to a unique byte sequence. The ISO/IEC 10646 standard
> uses the term “UCS transformation format” for UTF; the two terms are
> merely synonyms for the same concept.
>
> Each UTF is reversible, thus every UTF supports lossless round
> tripping: mapping from ***any*** Unicode coded character sequence S to a
> sequence of bytes and back will produce S again. To ensure round
> tripping, a UTF mapping must map ***all*** code points (***except surrogate
> code points***) to unique byte sequences. This includes reserved
> (unassigned) code points and the 66 noncharacters (including U+FFFE
> and U+FFFF).

So, as you can see, by definition, all UTF encodings (including UTF-8) must be able to handle ***all*** Unicode code points (except the surrogate code points of course, but they are not *real* characters anyways).

Additionally, here is a quote directly from the [Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404) that also talks about this:

> The Unicode Standard supports three character encoding forms: UTF-32,
> UTF-16, and UTF-8. Each encoding form maps the Unicode code points
> ***U+0000..U+D7FF and U+E000..U+10FFFF*** to unique code unit sequences.

As you can see, the specified range of characters covers the whole assigned Unicode range (excluding the surrogate character range of course).

Answer (score 1):

> is there a text that cannot be represented by UTF-8 character encoding?

Java strings use UTF-16, and standard UTF-8 is designed to handle *every* Unicode codepoint that UTF-16 can handle (and then some).

However, do be careful, because Java *also* uses a [Modified UTF-8](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8) in some areas, and that does have some differences/limitations from standard UTF-8.